# Cryptography. English "normal text"?

Tags: cryptography, frequency-analysis, frequency-distribution

I was asked to make a software that will encrypt and decrypt a "normal English" text based on letter [frequencies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequencies).

The question is where do I find some text samples where the official frequencies will match?

So far, I have tried ["War and Peace" by Lev Tolstoy](http://www2.hn.psu.edu/faculty/jmanis/tolstoy/w&p_complete.pdf), it didn't work well..

LE: I don't need just a list of words, I need a text sample to make some processing.
LE2: The goal is to guess 20 from 26 in a 2000 characters long text.

Comment: For future reference, the word is ENcrypt.

Comment: How far off is "War and Peace"?

Comment: IN, SHR, CUMW wrong, even on 2.6MB .txt file... I would expect wrong frequencies on smaller parts of the text.. but not on the whole book.

Comment: If I cut the file to ~100KB I can match about 6-10 letters, no more.

Comment: The goal is to guess 20 from 26 in a 2000 characters long text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're searching for [English text corpora](http://www.google.com/search?q=English+text+corpus), e.g. http://faculty.washington.edu/ebender/corpora/corpora.html#modern. Out of what's listed there, I know that Project Gutenberg is free; many of the others might not be.

I'm not sure what you mean by the official frequencies -- the point of the frequencies is to match what you find in the wild, and if they don't, that's the frequency table's problem.

Comment: thanks, found some text samples, going to test frequencies now.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [infochimps](http://infochimps.com/); they have a bunch of freely available datasets that may be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this list of English words:

http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/share/dict/